# IIF or case when in window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some timestamps in a table and I want to create a dummy variable (0 or 1) that tests if the row above is equal to the current row, after the timestamps are sorted. I need to do this in different partitions. Is there a window function that can do this in SQL Server?

So I know my partition by column and order by column. From my knowledge of window functions I need to perhaps use a rank function, but is there a way to write this with nested functions using `IIF` and `LEAD` or `LAG` to check for some condition between the rows in a partition?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no row "above".

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I will use order by in over() clause...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL table represent unordered sets.  If you have an ordering column separate from the timestamps you can use:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(timestamp) over (partition by <partition col> order by <order col>) = timestamp
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag   
from t;
```

Comment: Cool thanks! It says I have to wait before I can accept.

Comment: So it is perfectly fine to use case when like this? What about iif(col, true, false)?

Comment: @GordanLinoff: what if I want to order by the timestamp?

Comment: @David . . . You would use `order by` to return the results in the order you want.

Answer (score -2):

SQL is a set language, so there is no above or below, but they created something like that, limited portability, by popular demand.  You can write a procedure that processes the order'd rows remembering prior values, priming that memory with something for the first row.  Still no access to the next row!  Back to spreadsheets?  Or save the info for the current row and prior row until the next row, and output the row a row late, but then what about the last row?  Even in spreadsheets, you have a top and bottom row!

Comment: Yes when you sort then there is.